# Getting a specific part from a python string

Tags: python, data-science, geopy

In Geopy, whenever I print the location for example

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="TTT")
location = geolocator.geocode("Washington")
print(location.raw)
```

I get the result like this --> Washington, District of Columbia, United States

What I want is to print the country name which means everything after the last coma

How can I do this?

Comment: you can use split(',') function which returns list of values from it you can extract the last value see split() function and try!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split(splitString)` function, it will split your string at the possitions where it finds the defined `splitString`.

In your case it could be:

```
str = "Washington, District of Columbia, United States"
country = str.split(", ")[-1]
```

Note that I used ", ", not "," so you won't have a space in your resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way:

```
s = "Washington, District of Columbia, United States"
print(s.split(",")[-1].strip())
```

Comment: Than you so much Pablo, I can't thank you enough! You are a total Gem!

Answer (score 1):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="TTT")
location = geolocator.geocode("Washington")
print(location.raw.split(",")[-1])
```